# Requisição post usando curl

Tags: post, libcurl

Como faço uma requisição, após clicar em um botão, usado curl?

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>loja</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/template.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="topo">
  <div class="login">
   <form method="POST" action="requisicaoCurl.php" name="login">
    <input class="btn" type="text" placeholder="Usuário" name="usuario">
    <input class="btn" type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha">
    <button type="button" id="btn_entrar">Entrar</button>
   </form>
  </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

preciso somente, após clicar entrar fazer uma requisição post e voltar.

Comment: to usando laravel, no caso mas n preciso autenticar com token, é só uma requisição

Answer (score -1):

> **requisicaoCurl.php**

```
<?php
    //RECEBENDOOS VALORES dos campos usuario e senha, e armazenando em variaveis, $user $password
    $user=$_POST['usuario'];
    $password=$_POST['senha'];
    //EXIBIR OS VALORES DO FORMULARIO  acima da pagina que vai ser carregada.
    echo 'Valor digitado no campo name="usuario" :'.$user;
    echo 'Valor digitado no campo name="senha" :'.$password;
    //CARREGAR A PAGINA REQUISITADA, USANDO www.google.com.br como exemplo.
    $ch = curl_init('www.google.com.br');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    //EXIBINDO A PAGINA
    curl_exec($ch);
    // COMPLETANDO REQUISIÇÃO
    curl_close($ch);
    echo '1º - ALORES DO CAMPOS CAMPOS FORAM EXIBIDOS<br>
    2º - a pagina foi carregada<br>
    3º - a pagina foi exibida.<br>
    4º - exbi essa mensagem<br>
    ';
?>
```

Comment: após edição que le propus no formulario, a criação do arquivo: requisicaoCurl.php, seu formulário está pronto para ser processado e chamar uma pagina via curl. Agora você adequa a seus interesses o código php. Se a resposta satisfaz sua nessessidade, Marque a resposta como aceita.

Comment: Resolveu seu problema ?